# R: Replace all Values that are not equal to a set of values

Tags: r, replace, dplyr

All.

I've been trying to solve a problem on a large data set for some time and could use some of your wisdom.

I have a DF (1.3M obs) with a column called customer along with 30 other columns. Let's say it contains multiple instances of customers Customer1 thru Customer3000. I know that I have issues with 30 of those customers. I need to find all the customers that are NOT the customers I have issues and replace the value in the 'customer' column with the text 'Supported Customer'. That seems like it should be a simple thing...if it werent for the number of obs, I would have loaded it up in Excel, filtered all the bad customers out and copy/pasted the text 'Supported Customer' over what remained.

Ive tried replace and str_replace_all using grepl and paste/paste0 but to no avail. my current code looks like this:

```
    #All the customers that have issues
    out <- c("Customer123", "Customer124", "Customer125", "Customer126", "Customer127",  
    "Customer128", ..... , "Customer140")
    #Look for everything that is NOT in the list above and replace with "Enabled"
    orderData$customer <- str_replace_all(orderData$customer, paste0("[^", paste(out, collapse = 
    "|"), "]"), "Enabled Customers")
```

That code gets me this error:

```
    Error in stri_replace_all_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  : 
    In a character range [x-y], x is greater than y. (U_REGEX_INVALID_RANGE)
```

I've tried the inverse of this approach and pulled a list of all obs that dont match the list of out customers. Something like this:

```
     in <- orderData %>% filter(!customer %in% out) %>% select(customer) %>% 
     distinct(customer)
```

This gets me a much larger list of customers that ARE enabled (~3,100). Using the str_replace_all and paste approach seems to have issues though. At this large number of patterns, paste no longer collapses using the "|" operator. instead I get a string that looks like:

```
     "c(\"Customer1\", \"Customer2345\", \"Customer54\", ......)
```

When passed into str_replace_all, this does not match any patterns.

Anyways, there's got to be an easier way to do this. Thanks for any/all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a data.table approach.

First, some example data since you didn't provide any.

```
customer <- sample(paste0("Customer",1:300),5000,replace = TRUE)
orderData <- data.frame(customer = sample(paste0("Customer",1:300),5000,replace = TRUE),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
orderData <- cbind(orderData,matrix(runif(0,100,n=5000*30),ncol=30))
out <- c("Customer123", "Customer124", "Customer125", "Customer126", "Customer127",  "Customer128","Customer140")
```

```
library(data.table)
setDT(orderData)
result <- orderData[!(customer %in% out),customer := gsub("Customer","Supported Customer ",customer)]
result
                    customer        1        2         3        4         5         6        7        8         9
   1: Supported Customer 134 65.35091  8.57117 79.594166 84.88867 97.225276 84.563997 17.15166 41.87160  3.717705
   2: Supported Customer 225 72.95757 32.80893 27.318046 72.97045 28.698518 60.709381 92.51114 79.90031  7.311200
   3: Supported Customer 222 39.55269 89.51003  1.626846 80.66629  9.983814 87.122153 85.80335 91.36377 14.667535
   4: Supported Customer 184 24.44624 20.64762  9.555844 74.39480 49.189537 73.126275 94.05833 36.34749  3.091072
   5: Supported Customer 194 42.34858 16.08034 34.182737 75.81006 35.167769 23.780069 36.08756 26.46816 31.994756
  ---
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. My use case was a bit more complicated than I specified in the OP. But, I was able to use your syntax and modify a bit.                               
      orderData <- orderData[(!grepl(paste(out, collapse="|"), orderData$customer, ignore.case=TRUE)), customer := "Enabled Customers"]